# Is there an actual 4-bit integer data type in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I require a **4 bit** *integer* in a design for less memory use. In any version of **c++** ,**c++11** ,**c++14** any can be used for the design.

Comment: Make a struct with a 4-bit bitfield

Comment: No there isn't such type. But you can always use `uint8_t` and bit masking and shifting.

Comment: The smallest integer type in C++ is `char` which is usually 8 bits. Are you targeting a memory-constrained embedded system? Otherwise it's more work to try these kind of micro-optimizations (it will also make the code harder to read, understand and maintain). It might also be a bit of premature optimization. Please try to elaborate on *why* you want to use "less memory" in a way that will probably use more CPU cycles instead.

Comment: If you are genuinely interested in this topic, check out: CppCon 2016: Chandler Carruth “High Performance Code 201: Hybrid Data Structures"

Answer (score 8):

There is no native 4bit datatype. But you could use an 8bit one to hold two 4bit values in the high/low [nibble](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

Comment: nibble is also used only in the struct. Is there any direct way to use the 4 bit int

Comment: @AmanGupta _" Is there any direct way to use the 4 bit int"_ No.

Answer (score 4):

no, but you can use:

```
struct A {
   unsigned int value1 : 4;
   unsigned int value2 : 4;
};
```

Comment: But the struct also use memory space ,so how much the total space is used in this case.

Comment: @emlai That's unfortunately [not true](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5037c96e3494cf8).

Comment: It would be true if you used `uint8_t` or `char` instead (assuming 8-bit char)

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` always returns 1,  so nothing can be smaller than a char - even is char is not 8 bits wide.